# ffmpeg not working in laravel controller version 7

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Hello I am using Laravel Lumen in windows 10, I have installed the libraries in `C:\PATHPrograms` and I added environment variable and if I put `ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\videos\commercial-30-seconds-nextel-2.mp4 -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:01 -t 00:00:10 output.mp4` by VIA CMD if it recognizes me and exports the video in Computer (by default, if someone tells me how to change it, great), when I put it inside my controller nothing happens and I put a dd (system ($ myvar)) to see that it prints [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7B0F.png) and nothing prints nothing, I attach the image, please some help or other way to crop videos. That's the way I've installed it. I'm new user using ffmpeg , please help and thanks.

```html
  $myvar="ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\videos\comercial-30-segundos-nextel-2.mp4 -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:10 output.mp4";
      dd(system($myvar));
```

[variable value before doing system()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuYs4.png)

Comment: @llogan , what do you mean ? .   I think no , that code is to crop the video and It's not working in controller code ( Laravel) but if I put ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\videos\comercial-30-segundos-nextel-2.mp4 -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:10 output.mp4"   . It works and the output is always stored in Computer path ( I don't know why, I'd like to change it )

Comment: Make sure that ffmpeg.exe is reachable from your system's $PATH environment variable.

Comment: Ok, have you tried printing the $PATH variable from within Laravel to verify? or execute a batch script from within the controller?

Comment: sorry , @StarShine, do you mean, doing a dd($myvar) ? . I'm using windows OS, I guess that batch is for Linux

Comment: .bat scripts are as Windows as they come, but you can simply try `echo $PATH` instead of the `ffmpeg etc.. `

Comment: I will and I got the path  "ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\videos\comercial-30-segundos-nextel-2.mp4 -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:10 output.mp4"    between quotes

Comment: Ok, I'm seeing a lof of paths related to variable environment  and I see the path I've configured for FFMPEG.

Comment: Ok, so assuming the ffmpeg.exe is actually called, it should dump some results to `stdout` and you should try to capture it, for example by appending ` > log.txt ` to the command line. Be sure to try this and see if you get the `log.txt` file dumped. Finally, see if the mp4 path with the slashes is correctly parsed by the tool. I suggest to try with double backslashes or even forward slashes instead, because it's Windows.

Comment: I changed it with double backslashes and I added the line code       Log::info(system($myvar));
but it only stores in storage/logs something like this "  [2021-03-29 21:57:05] local.INFO:   
[2021-03-29 21:57:13] local.INFO:   
".   Is that you were saying about the log.txt?

Comment: try `$myvar="ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\videos\comercial-30-segundos-nextel-2.mp4 -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:10 output.mp4 > log.txt";
      dd(system($myvar));`